# Apache Flink: ClassNotFoundException on remote cluster

Tags: apache-flink

I'm running into a ClassNotFoundException only when I run my application on a standalone cluster (using flink cli). If i directly run the main class in my IDE, it's working fine. But using the following cli, it throws error:

`./bin/flink run /mnt/MykafkaConsumerApp.jar`

This is a spring boot app that I've packaged using maven (Apache Maven 3.3.9). I've verified the class is present in the jar as well.

The `execute()` call happens inside `MyWikiAnalysis` spring bean on PostConstruct.

Following are the cluster logs:

```
2019-05-02 14:54:32,984 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-05-02 14:54:32,986 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  Starting StandaloneSessionClusterEntrypoint (Version: 1.8.0, Rev:4caec0d, Date:03.04.2019 @ 13:25:54 PDT)
2019-05-02 14:54:32,986 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  OS current user: abhishek
2019-05-02 14:54:32,986 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  Current Hadoop/Kerberos user: <no hadoop dependency found>
2019-05-02 14:54:32,987 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM - Oracle Corporation - 1.8/25.112-b15
2019-05-02 14:54:32,987 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  Maximum heap size: 981 MiBytes
2019-05-02 14:54:32,987 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  JAVA_HOME: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_112
2019-05-02 14:54:32,987 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  No Hadoop Dependency available
2019-05-02 14:54:32,987 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  JVM Options:
2019-05-02 14:54:32,987 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     -Xms1024m
2019-05-02 14:54:32,987 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     -Xmx1024m
2019-05-02 14:54:32,987 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     -Dprofile=dev
2019-05-02 14:54:32,988 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     -Dlog.file=/mnt/installation/flink-1.8.0/log/flink-abhishek-standalonesession-4-abhishek-hp-probook-430-g3.log
2019-05-02 14:54:32,988 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/mnt/installation/flink-1.8.0/conf/log4j.properties
2019-05-02 14:54:32,988 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:/mnt/installation/flink-1.8.0/conf/logback.xml
2019-05-02 14:54:32,988 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  Program Arguments:
2019-05-02 14:54:32,988 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     --configDir
2019-05-02 14:54:32,988 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     /mnt/installation/flink-1.8.0/conf
2019-05-02 14:54:32,988 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     --executionMode
2019-05-02 14:54:32,988 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     cluster
2019-05-02 14:54:32,988 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  Classpath: /mnt/installation/flink-1.8.0/lib/MykafkaConsumerApp.jar:/mnt/installation/flink-1.8.0/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/mnt/installation/flink-1.8.0/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.15.jar:/mnt/installation/flink-1.8.0/lib/flink-dist_2.11-1.8.0.jar:::
2019-05-02 14:54:32,988 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-05-02 14:54:32,990 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - Registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2019-05-02 14:54:33,013 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: env.java.opts, "-Dprofile=dev"
2019-05-02 14:54:33,014 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.address, localhost
2019-05-02 14:54:33,014 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.port, 6123
2019-05-02 14:54:33,014 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.heap.size, 1024m
2019-05-02 14:54:33,014 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.heap.size, 1024m
2019-05-02 14:54:33,015 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots, 1
2019-05-02 14:54:33,015 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: parallelism.default, 1
2019-05-02 14:54:33,103 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - Starting StandaloneSessionClusterEntrypoint.
2019-05-02 14:54:33,103 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - Install default filesystem.
2019-05-02 14:54:33,110 INFO  org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem                           - Hadoop is not in the classpath/dependencies. The extended set of supported File Systems via Hadoop is not available.
2019-05-02 14:54:33,125 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - Install security context.
2019-05-02 14:54:33,134 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.security.modules.HadoopModuleFactory  - Cannot create Hadoop Security Module because Hadoop cannot be found in the Classpath.
2019-05-02 14:54:33,146 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.security.SecurityUtils               - Cannot install HadoopSecurityContext because Hadoop cannot be found in the Classpath.
2019-05-02 14:54:33,147 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - Initializing cluster services.
2019-05-02 14:54:33,368 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcServiceUtils         - Trying to start actor system at localhost:6123
2019-05-02 14:54:33,807 INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger                                  - Slf4jLogger started
2019-05-02 14:54:33,857 INFO  akka.remote.Remoting                                          - Starting remoting
2019-05-02 14:54:33,967 INFO  akka.remote.Remoting                                          - Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://flink@localhost:6123]
2019-05-02 14:54:33,978 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcServiceUtils         - Actor system started at akka.tcp://flink@localhost:6123
2019-05-02 14:54:33,999 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration                  - Config uses fallback configuration key 'jobmanager.rpc.address' instead of key 'rest.address'
2019-05-02 14:54:34,011 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServer                      - Created BLOB server storage directory /tmp/blobStore-7e302421-82c7-42bb-a384-f41bca73d2eb
2019-05-02 14:54:34,021 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServer                      - Started BLOB server at 0.0.0.0:33442 - max concurrent requests: 50 - max backlog: 1000
2019-05-02 14:54:34,044 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.MetricRegistryImpl           - No metrics reporter configured, no metrics will be exposed/reported.
2019-05-02 14:54:34,046 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - Trying to start actor system at localhost:0
2019-05-02 14:54:34,081 INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger                                  - Slf4jLogger started
2019-05-02 14:54:34,105 INFO  akka.remote.Remoting                                          - Starting remoting
2019-05-02 14:54:34,128 INFO  akka.remote.Remoting                                          - Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://flink-metrics@localhost:34524]
2019-05-02 14:54:34,133 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - Actor system started at akka.tcp://flink-metrics@localhost:34524
2019-05-02 14:54:34,141 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.FileArchivedExecutionGraphStore  - Initializing FileArchivedExecutionGraphStore: Storage directory /tmp/executionGraphStore-a02136d4-c34e-4202-8e4f-68ab77812bcc, expiration time 3600000, maximum cache size 52428800 bytes.
2019-05-02 14:54:34,183 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.TransientBlobCache              - Created BLOB cache storage directory /tmp/blobStore-e9345768-94e5-415a-a616-348365eaac2a
2019-05-02 14:54:34,270 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration                  - Config uses fallback configuration key 'jobmanager.rpc.address' instead of key 'rest.address'
2019-05-02 14:54:34,271 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.DispatcherRestEndpoint    - Upload directory /tmp/flink-web-b0de0d0c-3882-4ccf-a9bc-e77c48cc3c49/flink-web-upload does not exist, or has been deleted externally. Previously uploaded files are no longer available.
2019-05-02 14:54:34,272 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.DispatcherRestEndpoint    - Created directory /tmp/flink-web-b0de0d0c-3882-4ccf-a9bc-e77c48cc3c49/flink-web-upload for file uploads.
2019-05-02 14:54:34,276 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.DispatcherRestEndpoint    - Starting rest endpoint.
2019-05-02 14:54:34,583 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.WebMonitorUtils           - Determined location of main cluster component log file: /mnt/installation/flink-1.8.0/log/flink-abhishek-standalonesession-4-abhishek-hp-probook-430-g3.log
2019-05-02 14:54:34,584 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.WebMonitorUtils           - Determined location of main cluster component stdout file: /mnt/installation/flink-1.8.0/log/flink-abhishek-standalonesession-4-abhishek-hp-probook-430-g3.out
2019-05-02 14:54:34,805 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.DispatcherRestEndpoint    - Rest endpoint listening at localhost:8081
2019-05-02 14:54:34,806 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.DispatcherRestEndpoint    - http://localhost:8081 was granted leadership with leaderSessionID=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
2019-05-02 14:54:34,806 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.DispatcherRestEndpoint    - Web frontend listening at http://localhost:8081.
2019-05-02 14:54:34,929 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService              - Starting RPC endpoint for org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager at akka://flink/user/resourcemanager .
2019-05-02 14:54:34,959 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService              - Starting RPC endpoint for org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.StandaloneDispatcher at akka://flink/user/dispatcher .
2019-05-02 14:54:34,997 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager  - ResourceManager akka.tcp://flink@localhost:6123/user/resourcemanager was granted leadership with fencing token 00000000000000000000000000000000
2019-05-02 14:54:34,998 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.slotmanager.SlotManager  - Starting the SlotManager.
2019-05-02 14:54:35,018 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.StandaloneDispatcher      - Dispatcher akka.tcp://flink@localhost:6123/user/dispatcher was granted leadership with fencing token 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
2019-05-02 14:54:35,021 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.StandaloneDispatcher      - Recovering all persisted jobs.
2019-05-02 14:54:35,731 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager  - Registering TaskManager with ResourceID 1b12a8033d8a788148dc343b538d847c (akka.tcp://flink@172.16.118.168:45307/user/taskmanager_0) at ResourceManager
2019-05-02 14:55:22,480 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.StandaloneDispatcher      - Received JobGraph submission 6ccd855ac76bb63cb95103913c2efe95 (Flink Streaming Job).
2019-05-02 14:55:22,480 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.StandaloneDispatcher      - Submitting job 6ccd855ac76bb63cb95103913c2efe95 (Flink Streaming Job).
2019-05-02 14:55:22,535 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService              - Starting RPC endpoint for org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster at akka://flink/user/jobmanager_0 .
2019-05-02 14:55:22,545 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                  - Initializing job Flink Streaming Job (6ccd855ac76bb63cb95103913c2efe95).
2019-05-02 14:55:22,554 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                  - Using restart strategy NoRestartStrategy for Flink Streaming Job (6ccd855ac76bb63cb95103913c2efe95).
2019-05-02 14:55:22,571 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Job recovers via failover strategy: full graph restart
2019-05-02 14:55:22,579 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                  - Running initialization on master for job Flink Streaming Job (6ccd855ac76bb63cb95103913c2efe95).
2019-05-02 14:55:22,579 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                  - Successfully ran initialization on master in 0 ms.
2019-05-02 14:55:22,595 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                  - No state backend has been configured, using default (Memory / JobManager) MemoryStateBackend (data in heap memory / checkpoints to JobManager) (checkpoints: 'null', savepoints: 'null', asynchronous: TRUE, maxStateSize: 5242880)
2019-05-02 14:55:22,604 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobManagerRunner           - JobManager runner for job Flink Streaming Job (6ccd855ac76bb63cb95103913c2efe95) was granted leadership with session id 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 at akka.tcp://flink@localhost:6123/user/jobmanager_0.
2019-05-02 14:55:22,606 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                  - Starting execution of job Flink Streaming Job (6ccd855ac76bb63cb95103913c2efe95) under job master id 00000000000000000000000000000000.
2019-05-02 14:55:22,607 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Job Flink Streaming Job (6ccd855ac76bb63cb95103913c2efe95) switched from state CREATED to RUNNING.
2019-05-02 14:55:22,615 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Source: Custom Source (1/1) (98194ef84a5e0681a9db49772fa1e65a) switched from CREATED to SCHEDULED.
2019-05-02 14:55:22,631 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SlotPoolImpl      - Cannot serve slot request, no ResourceManager connected. Adding as pending request [SlotRequestId{d6bbb9779510f218ea06a212b8ddb3b3}]
2019-05-02 14:55:22,637 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows(5), ProcessingTimeTrigger, FoldFunction$1, PassThroughWindowFunction) -> Sink: Print to Std. Out (1/1) (b97895d8f20f026dc2e9417c44c86c30) switched from CREATED to SCHEDULED.
2019-05-02 14:55:22,640 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                  - Connecting to ResourceManager akka.tcp://flink@localhost:6123/user/resourcemanager(00000000000000000000000000000000)
2019-05-02 14:55:22,644 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                  - Resolved ResourceManager address, beginning registration
2019-05-02 14:55:22,644 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                  - Registration at ResourceManager attempt 1 (timeout=100ms)
2019-05-02 14:55:22,647 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager  - Registering job manager 00000000000000000000000000000000@akka.tcp://flink@localhost:6123/user/jobmanager_0 for job 6ccd855ac76bb63cb95103913c2efe95.
2019-05-02 14:55:22,664 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager  - Registered job manager 00000000000000000000000000000000@akka.tcp://flink@localhost:6123/user/jobmanager_0 for job 6ccd855ac76bb63cb95103913c2efe95.
2019-05-02 14:55:22,670 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                  - JobManager successfully registered at ResourceManager, leader id: 00000000000000000000000000000000.
2019-05-02 14:55:22,671 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SlotPoolImpl      - Requesting new slot [SlotRequestId{d6bbb9779510f218ea06a212b8ddb3b3}] and profile ResourceProfile{cpuCores=-1.0, heapMemoryInMB=-1, directMemoryInMB=0, nativeMemoryInMB=0, networkMemoryInMB=0} from resource manager.
2019-05-02 14:55:22,672 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager  - Request slot with profile ResourceProfile{cpuCores=-1.0, heapMemoryInMB=-1, directMemoryInMB=0, nativeMemoryInMB=0, networkMemoryInMB=0} for job 6ccd855ac76bb63cb95103913c2efe95 with allocation id c831433fe33220e01eab5c62a219593a.
2019-05-02 14:55:22,746 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Source: Custom Source (1/1) (98194ef84a5e0681a9db49772fa1e65a) switched from SCHEDULED to DEPLOYING.
2019-05-02 14:55:22,746 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Deploying Source: Custom Source (1/1) (attempt #0) to 1b12a8033d8a788148dc343b538d847c @ abhishek-hp-probook-430-g3 (dataPort=37667)
2019-05-02 14:55:22,763 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows(5), ProcessingTimeTrigger, FoldFunction$1, PassThroughWindowFunction) -> Sink: Print to Std. Out (1/1) (b97895d8f20f026dc2e9417c44c86c30) switched from SCHEDULED to DEPLOYING.
2019-05-02 14:55:22,764 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Deploying Window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows(5), ProcessingTimeTrigger, FoldFunction$1, PassThroughWindowFunction) -> Sink: Print to Std. Out (1/1) (attempt #0) to 1b12a8033d8a788148dc343b538d847c @ abhishek-hp-probook-430-g3 (dataPort=37667)
2019-05-02 14:55:23,656 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows(5), ProcessingTimeTrigger, FoldFunction$1, PassThroughWindowFunction) -> Sink: Print to Std. Out (1/1) (b97895d8f20f026dc2e9417c44c86c30) switched from DEPLOYING to RUNNING.
2019-05-02 14:55:23,765 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Source: Custom Source (1/1) (98194ef84a5e0681a9db49772fa1e65a) switched from DEPLOYING to FAILED.
org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskException: Could not instantiate outputs in order.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.getOutEdgesInOrder(StreamConfig.java:398)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.createRecordWriters(StreamTask.java:1164)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.<init>(StreamTask.java:212)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.<init>(StreamTask.java:190)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask.<init>(SourceStreamTask.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.loadAndInstantiateInvokable(Task.java:1405)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tp.flinktest.MyWikiAnalysis$2
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.execution.librarycache.FlinkUserCodeClassLoaders$ChildFirstClassLoader.loadClass(FlinkUserCodeClassLoaders.java:129)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil$ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.resolveClass(InstantiationUtil.java:78)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:791)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1909)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:566)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:552)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:540)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.readObjectFromConfig(InstantiationUtil.java:501)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.getOutEdgesInOrder(StreamConfig.java:395)
    ... 11 more
2019-05-02 14:55:23,768 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Job Flink Streaming Job (6ccd855ac76bb63cb95103913c2efe95) switched from state RUNNING to FAILING.
org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskException: Could not instantiate outputs in order.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.getOutEdgesInOrder(StreamConfig.java:398)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.createRecordWriters(StreamTask.java:1164)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.<init>(StreamTask.java:212)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.<init>(StreamTask.java:190)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask.<init>(SourceStreamTask.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.loadAndInstantiateInvokable(Task.java:1405)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tp.flinktest.MyWikiAnalysis$2
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.execution.librarycache.FlinkUserCodeClassLoaders$ChildFirstClassLoader.loadClass(FlinkUserCodeClassLoaders.java:129)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil$ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.resolveClass(InstantiationUtil.java:78)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:791)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1909)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:566)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:552)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:540)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.readObjectFromConfig(InstantiationUtil.java:501)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.getOutEdgesInOrder(StreamConfig.java:395)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Could you check that `com.tp.flinktest.MyWikiAnalysis$2` is actually part of `MykafkaConsumerApp.jar` and not dynamically generated?

Comment: @TillRohrmann I've double checked it. There are 3 classes showing in this package: `MyWikiAnalysis`, `MyWikiAnalysis$1` and `MyWikiAnalysis$2`. None of these are dynamically generated.

Comment: what's the flink version?

Comment: @孙兴斌 Flink 1.8.0

Answer (score 1):

you have to post the `pom.xml` that you use to create your jar file. I already have the same issue and I added the following lines on my `pom.xml`. Check if you already have these parameters in yours:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    ....
    <dependencies>
    ....
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Maven Shade Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- If you want to use ./bin/flink run <quickstart jar> uncomment 
                                the following lines. This will add a Main-Class entry to the manifest file -->
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>org.sense.flink.App</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                                <!-- This bit merges the various GeoTools META-INF/services files -->
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                            </transformers>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```